# For purposes of Alarm Manager, does a pendingintent have unique id for app or for device?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to ask about `AlarmManager`. When I need to cancel an alarm I must call cancel with the alarm's `PendingIntent`. So, is it possible to accidentally cancel an alarm that another app has set with the same `id`? Also, how can I find all alarms set with `AlarmManager` by my app?

Answer (score 0):

The alarms you create in your app are unique to your app and hence they can have same Ids used in another project/app.

There is no way to get all the alarms set in AlarmManager programmatically. You will have to maintain a list of alarms you set in preferences or in database.

Answer (score 0):

For cancellation, the PendingIntent is identified by the  contained `Intent` according to [filterEquals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)), which checks for "action, data, type, class, and categories", but doesn't look at the intent's extras.

As a rule of thumb, construct the pending intent as you did when you set the alarm and you'll cancel the right one.